# Restarting with adam

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, pytorch, gradient-descent, stochastic-gradient

I am training my network with early stopping strategy. I start with a higher learning rate, and based on validation loss, I need to restart training from an earlier snapshot.

I am able to save/load snapshot with model and optimizer `state_dicts`. No problem with that.

My question is, once I restart training, how do I set the learning rate of adam again? Should I restart adam fresh instead of using a `state_dict` or should I use
`optimizer.param_groups[0][‘lr’] = lr` to adjust learning rate with loaded optimizer `state_dict`?

For example,
I train my network with `lr = 1e-6` for 5 epochs, saved model and optimizer `state_dict`.
I am now restarting from epoch 6, but I need `lr = 1e-7` instead. What is the best approach for this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Looking at PyTorch's `torch.optim.lr_scheduler` code [here](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/optim/lr_scheduler.html), I can see that they set the parameter of the optimizer. Thus, that will be the best approach. The exact place I can see this is in `step` function of class `_LRScheduler` (in the above link).

You can do the same by

```
optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'] = lr
```

as you had mentioned yourself.

Comment: I dived further into the code, and I think I figured out the correct way to do this. Please check my answer.

Comment: No need to do all that, that single line `optimizer.param_groups[0]['lr'] = lr` is enough at the point where you need to change the learning rate. They have done it to formally define it in a class.

Comment: Interesting. Does that work even if there are multiple parameters set when initializing optimizer?

Comment: Yes, I think. It should work for any other parameters also (like weight decay or momentum). Only the parameter you change will be changed, others remain the same.

Answer (score 1):

Looking further into the scheduler code, I found the correct way to do it as:

```
def get_lr(gamma, optimizer):
    return [group['lr'] * gamma
            for group in optimizer.param_groups]

for param_group, lr in zip(optimizer.param_groups, get_lr(gamma, optimizer)):
    param_group['lr'] = lr
```